# bxslider custom next slide button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, bxslider

I'm working with a wordpress site that uses the jQuery bxslider script and am trying to code a a href link in the content of one of the slides that when clicked goes to the next slide.

My knowledge of php and how the bxsldier script works is beginner. I've tried copying html code that is used on the next slide arrow but that doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help on how to be able to place some code in the body of a page in wordpress (Next Slide) that when clicked transitions to the next slide.

Thank you!

Comment: Your requirement is if you click on image then it should go on next slide?

Comment: On that page, there's an 'enquire' button at the bottom. When clicked I want the sldier to move to the next slide. Just like the arrows on the edges do already.

Comment: If given solution is not working for you just let me know

Comment: is your solution working ?

Comment: Yes I have tested it earlier and it was working

Comment: Why have you removed your question? Maybe is useful for another user!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code in below code just provide id or class of next slider in "nextSelector" of your element it will start slide

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: 'Onward →',
  prevText: '← Go back'
});
```

Use http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors link for reference

Comment: Do I place the JS inside the <head> tag of header.php? And then in the page have a link say: <a href="" id="slider-next">Next Slide</a>?

Comment: I am not sure because I have placed in last of my page, you can try

Answer (score 0):

### Heading

### JS

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: 'Onward →',
  prevText: '← Go back'
});

### HTML

#### This div is outside of the slider

|

Give id  "slider-prev" and "slider-next" to your images.

Comment: I want to have a link in the page body that when clicked goes to the next slide only. i.e. <a href="" id="slider-next">Next Slide</a>.